# Dynamic hashtable columns/values

Tags: powershell

I have 3 items with a lot of sub-features and values.
I want to know if it is possible to create dynamic hashtable like this without hardcoding column names:

```
Item Sub-feature1 Sub-feature2 Sub-feature3 Sub-feature4 Sub-feature5
1    value        value1       value2                    value3
2                 value        value1       value2      
3    value        value1       value2       value3       value4
```

The first column is always Id but columns after that can be different.
Yes I can hardcode all of the possible options but they are like 50 and I want to know if there is easier way.

For now I tried with:

```
$itemData = New-Object PSObject
foreach ( $item in $items){
$itemData | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $subFeatureName -NotePropertyValue $subFeatureValue
}
```

Without success.

Comment: There is not enough information here to even begin to answer your question because the problem isn't well defined. I don't understand how you want the resulting hashtable structured (what is the key? what is the value?), or how the structure of your data turns into `$items` (i.e., I don't know what `$items` is), or how your data even indicates the sub-features. Is your input a CSV data file? A fixed width text file? JSON output? Database output? There's also no indication what your ultimate goal here is, making this smell like an XY problem.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.
Well the $items are bunch of System.Object, the key is that every $item has different System.Objects in it.